# Split list of string into list of lists based on substring limit

Tags: python, list

I have a list with items like:

```
['1 Paris-SG 42 20 13 3 4 +33',
 '2 Lille 42 20 12 6 2 +20',
 '3 Lyon 40 20 11 7 2 +20',
 '4 Monaco 36 20 11 3 6 +10']
```

and I want to split the string in above list to get the list of lists like:

```
[['1', 'Paris-SG', '42 20 13 3 4 +33'],
 ['2', 'Lille', '42 20 12 6 2 +20'],
 ['3', 'Lyon', '40 20 11 7 2 +20'],
 ['4', 'Monaco', '36 20 11 3 6 +10']]
```

Here's the code I tried, but I am not getting the desired result:

```
ligu1 = []
for i in (final):
    print(i)
    for elem in sorted(i):
        stat = ','.join(map(str, elem))
        ligu1.append(stat)
ligu1
```

which gives me:

```
['1, ,P,a,r,i,s,-,S,G, ,4,2, ,2,0, ,1,3, ,3, ,4, ,+,3,3',

 '2, ,L,i,l,l,e, ,4,2, ,2,0, ,1,2, ,6, ,2, ,+,2,0',

 '3, ,L,y,o,n, ,4,0, ,2,0, ,1,1, ,7, ,2, ,+,2,0',

 '4, ,M,o,n,a,c,o, ,3,6, ,2,0, ,1,1, ,3, ,6, ,+,1,0']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write *list comprehension* using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with *`maxsplit`* param as 2 to achieve this:

```
my_list = [
    '1 Paris-SG 42 20 13 3 4 +33',
    '2 Lille 42 20 12 6 2 +20',
    '3 Lyon 40 20 11 7 2 +20',
    '4 Monaco 36 20 11 3 6 +10'
]

new_list = [s.split(' ', 2) for s in my_list]
```

where `new_list` will hold:

```
[
    ['1', 'Paris-SG', '42 20 13 3 4 +33'], 
    ['2', 'Lille', '42 20 12 6 2 +20'],
    ['3', 'Lyon', '40 20 11 7 2 +20'],
    ['4', 'Monaco', '36 20 11 3 6 +10']
]
```

Comment: ah great really thank you very much I don't know how to make the list comprehension on everything with split ('', 2) thousand thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple way I could think it to make clear and easy to understand:

```
lista = ['1 Paris-SG 42 20 13 3 4 +33',
 '2 Lille 42 20 12 6 2 +20',
 '3 Lyon 40 20 11 7 2 +20',
 '4 Monaco 36 20 11 3 6 +10']

string =[]
number = []
for i in lista:
    string.append(i.split(" "))
    
arr = []

for i in range(len(string)):
    temp = ''
    arr.append(string[i][:2])
    for j in string[i][3:]:
        temp +=j
    arr[i].append(temp)
print(arr)
```